# xsl:match and xsl:apply within the same parent

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following xml structure (It is much longer and compicated in the real example)

```
<document>
    <node1>
       <child1/>
       <child2/>
       ...
  </node1>
  <anotherNode />
</document>
```

I want to create a template like

```
<xsl:template match="node1" mode="node1">
        <img alt="" src="{child1}" />
        ...
        ...

</xsl:template>
```

and to apply this template in another template like this

```
<xsl:template match="anotherNode">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node1" mode="node1" />
</xsl:template>
```

If the node1 tag had parent that would be easy to do, but I can't figure out how to match and apply template if it does not have a parent.

Comment: In your example, node1 does have a parent - the `document` element.  All elements have parents.

Comment: I know but if I select the document tag the template ouputs all the content, instead of the one I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:template match="anotherNode"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/node1" mode="node1" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

**Or alternatively**:

```
<xsl:template match="anotherNode"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../node1" mode="node1" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ah that's my fault The structure of my xml was more compicated, Now I I see that it worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [parent axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes), (`..` in [abbreviated syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)).

All elements in a document have a parent (see [DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1060184317))

Answer (score 1):

Well the posted input is not even well-formed (typo "docuemnt" in the start tag of the root element?) and the indentation is also not clear but as long as the `anotherNode` element and the `node1` elements are siblings you can do

```
<xsl:template match="anotherNode">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::node1" mode="node1"/>
</xsl:template>
```